# How do I send commands to NVMe drive over USB bridge?

Tags: linux, encryption, usb-drive, nvme, sata

I have been working with a self encrypting drive that I want to be able to send commands to identify and unlock in userspace. I've been able to send commands to NVMe and SATA drives with direct motherboard connections using the `sg` and `nvme_admin_cmd` structures and `ioctls`, as well as with a USB->SATA adapter.

However, I can't seem to send commands to an NVMe drive over a USB bridge. Just as a sanity check, I used `sedutil` to try and query the drive, and it can't send commands to it either.

Is there a certain driver I'm supposed to be using to handle the USB/NVMe use case? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the drive showing up as /dev/nvmeX? If not, the bridge is presenting it as USB mass storage so you can't do low level nvme commands.

Comment: It shows up as /dev/sdX. But the way my application works now, if the drive shows up as sd?, it send ATA passthrough commands. That works with a direct SATA connection and with a USB -> SATA bridge